# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') when using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm making a todolist (angela yu), i'm trying to write to a new database, but i keep getting error.this is the error:

```
C:\Users\tunji\Desktop\webdev\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3519
        for (let i = 0; i < error.writeErrors.length; ++i) {
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at C:\Users\tunji\Desktop\webdev\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3519:47
    at collectionOperationCallback (C:\Users\tunji\Desktop\webdev\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:133:26)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tunji\Desktop\webdev\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:160:11)        
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

this is the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


// const itemsSchema = {
//   name: String
// };

const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item({name: "Workout"});
const item2 = new Item({name: "skydive"});
const item3 = new Item({name: "bungee"});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
  if (err){
    console.log(err + "yea");
  } else {
    console.log("good to go");
  }
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {


  res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: items});

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

i've checked the server, deleted and installed the node module ,everything, still no fix,nothing at all

Comment: What version of mongoose you have installed? (look in package.json and package-lock.json)

Comment: @J.D. 6.8.3 that's it

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using localhost:27017
Rather use 127.0.0.1:27017

So it should look like this:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todolistDB")
```

Comment: This is not the reason of error

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot connect to mongoose, as per mongoose documentation connect is an async method.

Try waiting for connection to be established, then write to the database

example:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: items});
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});

async function connect() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB');
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Could not connect to MongoDB');
        throw error;
    }
    const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
    });
      
    const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);  
    const item1 = new Item({name: "Workout"});
    const item2 = new Item({name: "skydive"});
    const item3 = new Item({name: "bungee"});
    
    const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];
    
    Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
    if (err){
        console.log(err + "yea");
    } else {
        console.log("good to go");
    }
    });
      
}

connect();

``
```

Comment: it was a connection issue, i changed `mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB` to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todolistDB` and it worked

Comment: I think you should still await the connection to make sure that it's established at the moment you are trying to write to mongo.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have first to comment the tiem.insert and your array

```
const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item({name: "Workout"});
const item2 = new Item({name: "skydive"});
const item3 = new Item({name: "bungee"});

// const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

// Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
//   if (err){
//     console.log(err + "yea");
//   } else {
//     console.log("good to go");
//   }
```

after that run the app.js in the terminal, now move to the mongo or mongosh and write **show dbs**, you should now see the **todolistDB** already. so now you could go and uncomment the rest of your code and run thr app.js again