# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I want to insert the array from the server but it is showing this error.

Productdata.js:

```
const products = [
  {
    id: "products1",
    url: "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/150/150/kapoo7k0/electric-kettle/p/6/s/pigeon-favourite-original-imafs7xhj5uwgrh4.jpeg?q=70",
    detailUrl:
      "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/kapoo7k0/electric-kettle/p/6/s/pigeon-favourite-original-imafs7xhj5uwgrh4.jpeg?q=70",
    title: {
      shortTitle: "Home & Kitchen",
      longTitle: "Pigeon FAVOURITE Electric Kettle  (1.5 L, Silver, Black)",
    },
    price: {
      mrp: 1195,
      cost: 625,
      discount: "47%",
    },
    description:
      "This electric kettle from Pigeon will soon become a travelers best friend, a hostelite saviour and an answer to all the midnight cravings. With this handy appliance, you can boil water and use it to make instant noodles, packet soup, coffee and green tea.",
    discount: "Extra 10% Off",
    tagline: "Deal of the day",
  },
  {
    id: "products2",
    url: "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/kl6wx3k0/sandwich-maker/8/r/d/sandwich-01-flipkart-smartbuy-original-imagydds4zthxt8z.jpeg?q=70",
    detailUrl:
      "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/kl6wx3k0/sandwich-maker/8/r/d/sandwich-01-flipkart-smartbuy-original-imagydds4zthxt8z.jpeg?q=70",
    title: {
      shortTitle: "Sandwich Makers",
      longTitle: "Flipkart SmartBuy Sandwich 01 Grill  (Black)",
    },
    price: {
      mrp: 1499,
      cost: 899,
      discount: "40%",
    },
    description:
      "This non-stick sandwich toaster .easy to use and very handy. Directly hold over flame to make tasty toasts and toasted sandwiches. Specially designed by keeping your needs in mind, the sandwich maker makes whatever youre doing simpler, smarter and better",
    discount: "From 99+5% Off",
    tagline: "Pestige, Nova & more",
  },
  {
    id: "products3",
    url: "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/150/150/kohigsw0/resistance-tube/c/s/e/new-adjustable-single-resistance-tube-multicolor-na-ajro-deal-original-imag2xg88mhmwxz5.jpeg?q=70",
    detailUrl:
      "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/kohigsw0/resistance-tube/c/s/e/new-adjustable-single-resistance-tube-multicolor-na-ajro-deal-original-imag2xg88mhmwxz5.jpeg?q=70",
    title: {
      shortTitle: "Fitness Gear",
      longTitle:
        "AJRO DEAL New Adjustable Single Resistance Tube (Multicolor) Resistance Tube  (Multicolor)",
    },
    price: {
      mrp: 499,
      cost: 166,
      discount: "66%",
    },
    description:
      "This unique product can tone your back muscles, reduce belly fat, improve blood circulation and also improves your body posture. It increases the stamina, energy and vitality of the body. The elastic resistance of the rubber training rope can be used to train and exercise in whichever way you want, according to your physical needs.",
    discount: "Upto 70% Off",
    tagline: "Deal of the Day",
  },
  {
    id: "products4",
    url: "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/300/300/kll7bm80/smartwatch/c/1/n/43-mo-sw-sense-500-android-ios-molife-original-imagyzyycnpujyjh.jpeg?q=70",
    detailUrl:
      "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/kll7bm80/smartwatch/c/1/n/43-mo-sw-sense-500-android-ios-molife-original-imagyzyycnpujyjh.jpeg?q=70",
    title: {
      shortTitle: "Smart Watches",
      longTitle: "Molife Sense 500 Smartwatch  (Black Strap, Freesize)",
    },
    price: {
      mrp: 6999,
      cost: 4049,
      discount: "42%",
    },
    description:
      "The Molife Sense 500, a brilliant smartwatch with a beautiful large display. Say hello to the infinity 1.7-inch display with 2.5D curved edges. Thanks to seamless Bluetooth 5.0 connectivity, you wont have to keep waiting. Bring a change to your outfit every day with changeable straps. A splash of color every day keeps the boredom away.",
    discount: "Grab Now",
    tagline: "Best Seller",
  },
  {
    id: "products5",
    url: "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/k3uhhu80/hair-dryer/n/m/t/nova-2800-w-professional-nhp-8220-original-imafmvwfhmzsxdrw.jpeg?q=70",
    detailUrl:
      "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/k3uhhu80/hair-dryer/n/m/t/nova-2800-w-professional-nhp-8220-original-imafmvwfhmzsxdrw.jpeg?q=70",
    title: {
      shortTitle: "Trimmers, Dryers & more",
      longTitle: "Nova Professional NHP 8220 Hair Dryer  (1800 W, Multicolor)",
    },
    price: {
      mrp: 1899,
      cost: 1124,
      discount: "40%",
    },
    description: "",
    discount: "From ₹499",
    tagline: "Kubra, Nova & more",
  },
];

module.exports = products;
```

productSchema.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  url: String,
  detailUrl: String,
  title: Object,
  price: Object,
  description: String,
  discount: String,
  tagline: String,
});

const Products = new mongoose.model("products", productSchema);

module.exports = Products;
```

Defaultdata.js:

```
const Products = require("./models/productSchema");
const productsdata = require("./constant/Productdata");

const DefaultData = async () => {
  try {
    const storeData = await Products.insertMany(productsdata);
    console.log(storeData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error" + error.message);
  }
};

module.exports = DefaultData;
```

db.sj:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const colors = require("colors");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
    console.log(`Mongodb Connected ${mongoose.connection.host}`.bgGreen.white);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Mongodb Server Issue ${error}`.bgRed.white);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

.env

```
PORT = 8080
NODE_MODE = development
MONGO_URL = mongodb+srv://<ID>:<Password>cluster0.gmwgmv0.mongodb.net/Amazon_website
JWT_SECRET = my-32-character-ultra-secure-and-ultra-long-secret
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const colors = require("colors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
// const Products = require("./models/productSchema");
const DefaultData = require("./defaultdata");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const router = require("./routes/routes");
dotenv.config();

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

//routes
app.use(router);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server is running in ${process.env.NODE_MODE} Mode on port ${process.env.PORT}`
      .bgCyan.white
  );
});

DefaultData();
```

I check some solution form some question but those didn'y work for me.
Here is a view of how the error. Looks like:
[image: Error from the terminal]

So I am looking for the solution .If anyone can help me then it will be nice for me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [post](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongoose-error-on-insertmany/210466/2), the problem will be solved after establishing the database connection.

Comment: Database connection is established in the config file I didn't attached it. But in the server.js file you may see I import ConnectDB from config folder db.js file.

Comment: I also update the code with the required file you may need to check the for solving the error.

Comment: Were you able to successfully add, update, or delete documents in the database before this issue occurred? I also noticed that you included the `.env` file and intentionally hid the `MONGO_URL`. Did you modify the `<ID>` and `<Password>` parameters in your local setup?

Comment: Yes I modified. I intentionally modified it while I was posting. Before this I could do the operation. So I can assure you that the Mongo_URL is completely fine. The problem maybe occuring because of something else

Comment: Could you try to add to callback function to `insertMany`? [From documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.insertMany) you can see example. So you can see if there is a validation error or not.

Comment: Error: MongooseError: Model.insertMany() no longer accepts a callback
    at Function.insertMany


It is not accepting callback function

Comment: Could you try promise instead of await, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780544/20250421)

Comment: I tried that too that is showing:
operation `products.coutDocumets() buffering timed out after 10000ms`

after that I increase the time. But still it shows the same error

Comment: Can you give any other solution

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why this is happening, but as I mentioned earlier, it might be due to a connection problem like the one described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75458505/20250421) post.

Comment: But my backend connected to server. i checked. But I can not store the productdata into the server. It is saying that `products.coutDocumets() buffering timed out after 10000ms`

Comment: Instead of adding multiple product at once, could you try to add single product with `create` so we can be sure it's not about it so you can search problem for `insertMany`.